# Read Data of user Control in sharepoint visual web part

Tags: visual-web-part, user-controls

I developed an user control and added that user control in my visual web part multiple times.

Three times manuallay and then dynamically. I can fetch the data of the user control which i have added manually But I am unable to fetch the data of the user control that I have added dynamically. Please suggest.

Codes of the visual web part are as follows

Visual web part ascx page

```
// my user control registration in web part
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControlsTkt" TagName="MultiSubTkts" Src="../ucMutlSubTicket.ascx" %>
<%@ Reference Control="../ucMutlSubTicket.ascx" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatpnl" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="dynamicpnl" runat="server">
                  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="yellow-headds CSSTableGenerator contentSL2" runat="server" id="tblDynmcContorls">
                         <tr class="small-box">
                            <td style="background: #f1f1f1;">
                            <UserControlsTkt:MultiSubTkts id="mutlisubtktrow0" runat="server"></UserControlsTkt:MultiSubTkts>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="small-box">
                             <td style="background: #f1f1f1;">
                            <UserControlsTkt:MultiSubTkts id="mutlisubtktrow1" runat="server"></UserControlsTkt:MultiSubTkts>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="small-box">
                           <td style="background: #f1f1f1;">
                                <UserControlsTkt:MultiSubTkts id="mutlisubtktrow2" runat="server" ></UserControlsTkt:MultiSubTkts>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="addnewSctn" OnClick="addnewSctn_Click" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../../../Style Library/SCMSModule/images/plus_16.png" class="add-txt-sub-category" />
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="removeNewSctn"  OnClick="removeNewSctn_Click" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../../../Style Library/SCMSModule/images/minus_16.png" />

                            </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="small-box">
                          <td>
                            <%--<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcholdr" runat="server">

                            </asp:PlaceHolder>--%>

                              </td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr class="tr-btn-event">
                            <td valign="middle" align="center" colspan="2" class="tdStl popupmargin">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAddMultSubTkt" runat="server" Text="Create" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnAddMultSubTkt_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code behind file

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["iValue"] != null)
            {
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["iValue"]);
                for (int j = 3; j < i; j++)
                {
                    ucMutlSubTicket ac = (ucMutlSubTicket)LoadControl("../ucMutlSubTicket.ascx");
                    ac.ID = "mycontrols" + j;
                    ac.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    //plcholdr2.Controls.Add(ac);
                    //plcholdr2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR />"));
                    HtmlTableRow tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
                    HtmlTableCell tb = new HtmlTableCell();
                    tb.Style.Add("background", "#f1f1f1");
                    tb.Controls.Add(ac);
                    tRow.Attributes.Add("class", "small-box");
                    tRow.Controls.Add(tb);
                    tblDynmcContorls.Rows.Add(tRow);
                }
            }
        }

 protected void btnAddMultSubTkt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ucMutlSubTicket objtstCntrl = (ucMutlSubTicket)dynamicpnl.FindControl("mycontrols3"); // here i dont  get the control
            ucMutlSubTicket objtstCntrl1 = (ucMutlSubTicket)dynamicpnl.FindControl("mutlisubtktrow0"); // here I get the control
            TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)objtstCntrl.FindControl("txtSubjct");
            string strFirstName = objTextBox.Text;
        }

protected void addnewSctn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 3;
            if(ViewState["iValue"]!=null)
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["iValue"]);
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["iValue"]) < 3)
            {
                i = 3;
            }
            i += 1;
            ViewState["iValue"] = i;
            this.Page_Init(null, null);
            //this.Page_Load(null, null);
        }

        protected void removeNewSctn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int i=0;
            if (ViewState["iValue"] != null)
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["iValue"]);
                i -= 1;
                ViewState["iValue"] = i;
                this.Page_Init(null, null);
                //this.Page_Load(null, null);
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["iValue"]) < 3)
            {
                i = 3;
            }
        }
```

Please help.